# Twitter Bootstrap: Multiple responsive collapsable navs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.  I want to have two (or more) navigations that when viewed on mobile, collapse into a dropdown.

This can easily be done once on a page, but I can't figure out how to have multiple responsive/collapsable navigations.

This code works to create one nav that collapses on mobile:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">groups</a>

<div class="nav-collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But how can I make a 2nd nav?

I tried duplicating this code and changing `data-target=".nav-collapse"` to `data-target=".nav-collapse2"` but that doesn't work.

Does Twitter Bootstrap offer the ability to have 2 or more responsive navs on a page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track.

`.nav-collapse` is used internally by bootstrap to actually make the navigation collapse responsively. Instead of using `.nav-collapse2` as a `data-target`, use your own class/id (in addition to using `.nav-collapse`)

Here's an example:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".col1">groups</a>
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".col2">groups2</a>

<div class="nav-collapse col1">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-collapse col2">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Nav Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Link2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz85X/).

Comment: Great! This piece of information was missing in the documentation, as far as I could tell anyway.

Comment: if you click both buttons, you get both menus in one. doesn't collaps others when a button is clicked

Comment: Your answer just saved me a couple of hours, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I started out the same as @gurch101 said, then used this to hide the other menu.

```
// Only show one navigation at a time
jQuery(function($){
  $('.col1').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    var otherNav = $('.col2');
    if (otherNav.is(':visible')) {
      otherNav.collapse('hide');
    }
  });
  $('.col2').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    var otherNav = $('.col1');
    if (otherNav.is(':visible')) {
      otherNav.collapse('hide');
    }
  });
});
```